# Is Any Coordinate (x(t), dx(t)/dt) Cycloid?

Tags: cycloid

Today I had learned cycloid which well parametarized with t as (t-sint, 1-cost)

What looks peculiar with this notation is that coordinate y is differentiated form of x.

Thus I had questioned myself "any coordinate (x(t), dx(t)/dt) Cycloid?" which mean there exist unique circle that denotes cycloidic movement.

+additional question : Is there any way to close out t and make the cycloid notation in a form of y=f(x)?

Comment: Are you asking whether every cycloid can be written in the form $t \mapsto \langle f(t), f^\prime(t)\rangle$?

Comment: @user326210 yes it is